# Eclipse program arguments not working (java)?

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line-arguments

I usually run this program via a command line like so:

```
java Program <TestClass.java
```

Which as I understand, forces the contents of TestClass.java to the console as user input.
i.e. It would be like executing

```
java Program
```

and then typing what ever is in TestClass.java

My problem is getting this happening in Eclipse. I can't figure out how to do it.
I would have thought that adding

```
<TestClass.java
```

to the program arguments in the run configuration would work, but it seems not.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Is it possible that it's actually working but you have the wrong working path?

Comment: TestClass.java is in the same folder as Program, so I wouldn't think it's that?

Comment: Eclipse supports only JVM/Program arguments. But you are passing DOS commnad < Testclasss.java as argumaent so it wont't work in eclipse.

Comment: OK, that makes more sense, is there a way to do what I'm talking about in eclipse, or do I have to write up some code to read in the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding this on top of your main.

```
InputStream in;
if (args.length > 0) {
  in = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
} else {
  // fallback
  in = System.in;
}
```

And then you add the filename as an argument, as if you're running `java Program TestClass.java`. This way, it will work whether you run it as before or using the filename as an argument.